# How to Combine Bernoulli Distribution with Exponential?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, zero-inflation, bernoulli-distribution

I understand a similar question has been asked before but it was closed because the OP left.

I have a situation where I have a continuous variable, which can take values between 0.0 -> ~0.1. It really looks like an exponential distribution in histogram plots.

However, the value 0.0 comes up 70% of the time, so I feel the exponential distribution isn't a great fit, instead, it would be better to somehow combine the Bernoulli distribution with it.

The end goal is to figure out if a random variable's probability is < 0.05, after modelling said distribution.

Example: 
I guess the best way to do this is to say ...

- If 0.0 comes, say the probability is 0.7
- If > 0.0 come up, model the exponential distribution of the rest of the data, and scale all probabilities by multiplying it by 0.3.

Is this a common thing people do? I'm not coming from a stats background, so I would like some advice on all this please.

Comment: The solution requires more information about the model for the data, but key words for searching include *zero inflation,* *mixture distributions,* *delta distributions,* and possibly even *rounding.*

Comment: Thank you for the help.